# SQL Azure and VS 2010B2 or SSMSE 2008

Tags: sql, connection, visual-studio-2010, azure-sql-database

Ok, I see that people have asked this question before, but I'm seeing some conflicting statements.

Can I, or can I not, connect directly to my SQL Azure database from SSMSE 2008?  I see posts from before November that the SSMS 2008 RC would be able to connect directly - so I don't understand why the newest SSMSE cannot connect.

Is it just a problem with the Express version of SSMS?  Where can I find the "non-Express" version, if there is one?

I *can* connect to the database via the cancel and connect method - however, you don't get object explorer that way.  I see that there are add-ons for VS.Net to allow you to explore the database but I wanted to do it with the base apps if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Ah, I see, I think I was confused on SQL 2008 R2 being before SSMSE, but I don't think that's the case.

Trying out SQL 2008 R2 now from here: http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/R2Downloads.aspx#CTP  Will report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I was right (in my comment) go to this link http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/R2Downloads.aspx#CTP and download the SQL 2008 R2 CTP's version of SSMS.  Then you connect to sql azure all normal like.